# Emailing text files as attachments from rake tasks, files are incomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, email, file-handling

I have a rake task that does a lot, but WRITES whatever it does on to a text file as below,

```
handler = File.open("cheese.txt", "a+")

handler.write("====Starting write!====\n")

handler
```

Now, Im catching the CTRL + C event as below,

```
Kernel.trap('INT') { 

 email_files # A method that cd to a PATH and attaches "cheese.txt" and use RAILS MAILERS to email 

 abort("Files Emailed, kernel trapped!")

}
```

**Problem is, the delivered text files doesn't  have any content the first time I do a CTRL+C,
but from the next time it delivers it right.**

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the file after you added a new line:

```
File.open("cheese.txt", "a+") do |handler|
  handler.write("====Starting write!====\n")
end
```

UPD: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-open:

*With no associated block, File.open is a synonym for ::new. If the optional code block is given, it will be passed the opened file as an argument and the File object will automatically be closed when the block terminates.*

Comment: Where are you closing the file?

Comment: When a block is given to File.open, the file gets closed automatically, even if an exception occurs during the execution of the block.